# Issue facing when progressbar.setprogress(0)

Tags: android, android-progressbar

I have a progressbar in a viewpager page 0.
This is the progressbar :

```
 <ProgressBar
                        android:id="@+id/mytask_today_progressBar"
                        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
                        android:layout_width="113dp"
                        android:layout_height="113dp"
                        android:indeterminate="false"
                        android:max="100"
                        android:progress="0"
                        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/custom_progress_small"
                        android:secondaryProgress="0" />
```

Now when that page is loaded, I set the progressbar to 0 and i get perfect screen like this below :

[image]

and this is the code I use :

```
mainActivity.sout("per_mytask_today : "+per_mytask_today);
    mytask_today_progressBar.setProgress(1);
    mainActivity.sout("mytask_today_progressBar.getprogress() : "+mytask_today_progressBar.getProgress());

    mytask_week_progressBar.setProgress(0);

    mytask_today_progresstxt.setText(1+"");
    mytask_week_progresstxt.setText(0+"");
```

and when I swap the pages of view pager like this and come back to the same page, the progressbar set to 0 is changed. Like this :

[image]

[image]

As you can see the progressbar set to 1(or as a matter of fact any other value from 1-100) does not change, only changes for 0.

This is the drawable i have used for this (is this creating an issue):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
    <item>
        <!-- Our second ring -->
        <shape android:shape="ring"
            android:useLevel="true"
            android:innerRadius="40dp"
            android:thicknessRatio="8">
            <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimaryDark"> </solid>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: I think your last line of code always makes the text to be `0` and does not matter what the actual value is. `mytask_week_progresstxt.setText(0+"")`. So basically you need to change the `.setText` to be what ever value and not make it static.

Comment: No, but it is working for values from 1-100. only for 0 it is causing issue

Answer (score 0):

Its more likely depends on where you set that progress. Ideally you should put that code inside `onPageSelected`

```
viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {

       //Set your progress here 

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: but why does it not cause problem when i set value other than 0

Comment: You probably set that setting code in somewhere at initial state which call once when your ViewPager call and that isn't suppose to be called on your page swipe .